Question about a proof that an elliptic group generated using a singular curve with a self-intersection is isomorphic to an multiplicative group
I'm reading a proof on page 63 of this book:
I'm struggling on the simplification process that derives $(2.11)$, in which it substitutes $x_1, \ x_2, \ x_3, \ y_1, \ y_2$ into $$x_3= \left(\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\right)^2 - a - x_1 - x_2,$$ where $a$ comes from the curve $y^2=x^2(x-a^2)$.
Can someone figure out the simplification process that the book omits?
Or is there any other way to show the elliptic group generated by a curve with a self intersection is isomorphic to a multiplicative group?
The part I'm struggling with is in this image, and the full proof can be found using the link of the book.
